# scala-submit java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

spark 2.7 scala 2.12.7 ,when i use spark-submit submit a simple project --WordCount, i ensure package and className is OK, but still have  a error
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
as my code:

1../bin/spark-submit --master spark://localhost.localdomain:7077 --class sparkTes.WordCount.scala  /java/spark/scala.jar

2.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Feo.png)
3.spark code

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordcount");
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val input = sc.textFile("/java/text/scala.md", 2).cache()
    val lines = input.flatMap(line=>line.split(" "))
    val count = lines.map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey{case (x,y)=>x+y}
    val output = count.saveAsTextFile("/java/text/WordCount")
  }
```

Comment: You have to just provide the classname. Drop the .scala extension. `--class sparkTes.WordCount`  . Also check whether `sparkTes` is correct package nameor not

Comment: yes. also extract your jar check your class is there or not.

Comment: yeah，jar do not hava error,now,i face the other porblem... when i submit my project ,after 3min, it will be killed,i want to know why....why the project be killed